# Definition of static property of object in OOP

Tags: terminology, reference-request, object-oriented

Grady Booch in [Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X) says:

> The state of an object encompasses all of the (usually static) properties of the object plus the current (usually dynamic) values of each of these properties ...

Then:

> Another property of a vending machine is that it can accept money. This is a static
> (i.e., fixed) property, meaning that it is an essential characteristic of a vending
> machine.

Then:

> All properties have some value. This value might be a simple quantity, or it might
> denote another object.

I am in doubt in about "`the ability of accepting money`" is a real property. Instead it seems it describes a behavior. Also Grady Booch says "All properties have some value."; but what is the value of "`the ability of accepting money`"?

Comment: (What if the "property" was characterised as *currently accepting money*?)

Comment: @greybeard Please add more details. I did not understand your opinion.

Comment: How much difference would the wording used to characterise a "property" make? While the *ability of accepting money* looks a prerequisite for commercial vending machines, "entry slots" may be welded shut/vandalised, controls unwilling to accept money when out of supplies, a display might show `not accepting coins` (or whatever "electronic" means of payment) for reasons unspecified. If your problem is in this domain, give an example of a (characterisation of a) property you'd accept *in your post*. Or do you think properties need to be mutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He apparently means to say that the existence of a particular property is usually common to every instance of a class (*static*, in that sense), while its value is not.

For example, *time_of_birth* is a property common to all *Person*s, while its value is not.